# Error on PL/SQL script datamart time table

Tags: oracle, date

I'm using this script to generate time table on a datawarehouse on oracle 11g express. This is the table

[image]

But when I compile, it gives me this error:
[image: this error].

The following script is to generate time dimension. I remember using the same code a year ago, but now it gives me the error that I mentioned:

```
CREATE or replace procedure date_manag is
date_debut DATE;
date_loop DATE;
date_fin DATE;
jour BINARY_INTEGER;
mois BINARY_INTEGER;
annee BINARY_INTEGER;
trim BINARY_INTEGER;
nom Varchar2(20);
Begin
date_debut:=TO_DATE('20/01/2012','dd/mm/yyyy');
date_fin:=TO_DATE('20/12/2012','dd/mm/yyyy');
date_loop:=date_debut;
WHILE date_loop <=date_fin
 LOOP
 select extract(day from date_loop) into jour from dual;
 select extract(month from date_loop) into mois from dual;
 select extract(year from date_loop) into annee from dual;
 CASE 
  WHEN mois=1 THEN nom :='JANVIER';
  WHEN mois=2 THEN nom :='FEVRIER';
  WHEN mois=3 THEN nom :='MARS';
  WHEN mois=4 THEN nom :='AVRIL';
  WHEN mois=5 THEN nom :='MAI';
  WHEN mois=6 THEN nom :='JUIN';
  WHEN mois=7 THEN nom :='JUILLET';
  WHEN mois=8 THEN nom :='AOUT';
  WHEN mois=9 THEN nom :='SEPTEMBRE';
  WHEN mois=10 THEN nom :='OCTOBRE';
  WHEN mois=11 THEN nom :='NOVEMBRE';
  else   nom:='DECEMBRE';
END CASE;
 CASE 
  when mois in(1,2,3) THEN trim :=1;
  when mois in(4,5,6) THEN trim :=2;
  when mois in(7,8,9) THEN trim :=3;
  else trim:=4;
 END CASE;
 INSERT into QOS.TEMPS VALUES( CASE   
when mois in(10,11,12) THEN annee||jour||mois 
ELSE annee||jour||'0'||mois 
END  
,annee,mois,jour,trim,jour || '/' || mois || '/' || annee,nom);

select ADD_MONTHS(date_loop,1) into date_loop from dual;
END LOOP;
END;
/
[this is my table][2]
```

Thanks

Comment: You're inserting 7 columns into `QOS.TEMPS`. How many columns does the table actually have?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i have 7 columns 
now i got this error :
Erreur(43,2): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NATIVE INTEGER

Comment: add the table schema to the question.

Comment: This is the table  http://i.stack.imgur.com/zpPE3.png

Comment: The columns in your `INSERT` statement don't match up with the columns in the table. You're putting `jour/mois/annee` in the `TRIMESTRE` column, and you're putting `annee||jour||mois` in `ID_DATE`.

Comment: so, do u have any suggestion to resolve this ?

Comment: List the columns explicitly in the `INSERT` statement, so you can be sure you're putting the correct values in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in your `INSERT` statement are not in the same order as the columns in the table. It's best not to rely on the order of the columns, you should list the columns explicitly.

```
INSERT into QOS.TEMPS (ID_DATE, ANNEE, MOIS, JOUR, TRIMESTRE, DATETIME, NOM)
VALUES( CASE   
            WHEN mois > 9 THEN annee||jour||mois 
            ELSE annee||jour||'0'||mois 
        END  
        ,annee,mois,jour,trim,jour || '/' || mois || '/' || annee,nom);
```

Comment: an other thing, when i compiled the script i got only the 20th day from each month, so if i want to get all days of the month what i do ?

Comment: Use `ADD_DAYS` instead of `ADD_MONTHS` when you increment `date_loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL

```
select extract(year from date_loop) into annee from dual;
```

is returning an integer value for year, a column which is expecting a DATE.